How to Modify a Scrapy Spider to Use Rule and LinkExtractor for Extracting Product Links?
I'm working on a Scrapy project and have a custom spider defined as follows:

class JosephCrawlSpider(Spider):
    parse_spider = JosephParseSpider()

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            category = self.extract_category_from_url(url)
            yield Request(
                url, callback=self.parse, cookies=self.cookies,
                meta={'category': category}
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        product_links = response.css('.product-name a.name-link::attr(href)').getall()

        if not product_links:
            return

        category = response.meta.get('category', 'unknown')
        for link in product_links:
            yield response.follow(
                link, callback=self.parse_product, cookies=self.cookies,
                meta={'category': category}
            )

        start = int(response.url.split('start=')[-1].split('&')[0])
        next_start = start + 12

        next_page = (
            f"https://www.joseph-fashion.com/en-gb/womens/"
            f"?start={next_start}&sz=12&format=page-element&rowNumber=4"
            f"&currentView=model_view"
        )
        yield Request(
            url=next_page, callback=self.parse, cookies=self.cookies,
            meta={'category': category}
        )

    def parse_product(self, response):
        response.meta['raw_product'] = response
        yield from self.parse_item(response)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        return self.parse_spider.parse(response)

    def extract_category_from_url(self, url):
        parts = url.split('/')
        try:
            start_index = parts.index("womens")
            return parts[start_index:start_index + 3]
        except ValueError:
            return []



I would like to refactor this crawler to use Scrapy's Rule and LinkExtractor to handle the extraction of product links and pagination. How can I modify the spider to utilize these classes?
I'm particularly interested in how to set up Rule for both extracting product links and handling pagination in the JosephCrawlSpider class.
Any guidance or examples on how to integrate Rule and LinkExtractor would be greatly appreciated!

It usually doesn't make sense to downgrade a normal spider to CrawlSpider.

Yes, but I must do it.

The scrapy documentation itself is very elaborate. For product links its pretty straightforward and pretty simple. You can refer to the  example here
. To extract links based on css/xpath selectors, you can make use of restrict_css/restrict_xpath(https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#topics-link-extractors)
As for the pagination, you can either create a callback function to extract links like you have now. But if you really want to create a Rule for that, you can:

Create a pagination class with extract_links method which returns a list of Link objects.
Create an instance of pagination class instead of the LinkExtractor object, inside the Rule()

